# Is this a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the map $f \mapsto f(0)$ from $\mathcal C([0,1])$ into $\mathbb R.$ Here $\mathcal C([0,1])$ is the space of continuous real functions on $[0,1]$ with the usual sup metric. Show that this is a quotient map.

How do we prove continuity of $f$ ?

Comment: If the map is a quotient map, then it is automatically continuous

Comment: @user99680 Towards proving that it is a quotient map, we are required to prove continuity, that is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to use the fact that $\mathcal{C}([0,1])/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ where $f\sim g$ iff $f(0)=g(0)$. The homeomorphism $\phi$ is given by $\phi([f]_{\sim})=f(0)$ which is easily proven to be a continuous bijection, as is the inverse given by $\phi^{-1}(r)=[c_r]_{\sim}$ with $c_r(x)=r$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Then, because the canonical map $q\colon\mathcal{C}([0,1])\to\mathcal{C}([0,1])/{\sim}$ is a quotient map, and the composition of a quotient map with a homeomorphism is a quotient map, we must also have $\phi \circ q=f$ is a quotient map.

This pushes the hard work from showing that a map is a quotient to showing that a different map is a homeomorphism. Opinions will vary as to whether this is easier or not.

Comment: @ Daniel Rust Brilliant! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The map is clearly onto. It is easy to see it is continuous, even lipschitz: $\lvert f(0) - g(0)\rvert ≤ \lVert f - g \rVert$. The map is not only quotient but even open quotient, so it remains to note that it is open – just use basic open set in $C[0, 1]$ (the tunnels) – their images are just intervals.